# Why would you force open a new connection in MSSQL and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

In the function [mssql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php), there is a fourth parameter called **new_link**.

> If a second call is made to mssql_connect() with the same arguments,
>   no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of
>   the already opened link will be returned. This parameter modifies this
>   behavior and makes mssql_connect() always open a new link, even if
>   mssql_connect() was called before with the same parameters.

I've noticed that a number of our scripts have been setting this parameter to true. The problem is, the person who made this decision can no longer be reached and I'm really struggling to think of a valid (read: sane) reason why a new connection should be forced open when a valid connection already exists.

Note that the function mysql_connect also has a similar param.

Comment: This might help you to understand it better - [link](http://ulyssesonline.com/2012/04/09/mysql-mysql_connect-new_link/)

Comment: @alphawow Seems like bad coding.

Answer (score 0):

there surely are only quite rare use cases.

My understanding is this:
`<vendor>_connect()` opens a connection to the DB server, not to a specific database.
If you want to work with different DBs on the same server within the same request, you'll need to manage the access - either several calls to `<vendor>_select_db` ([mssql_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-select-db.php)) on the same connection, or different connections with different selected DBs to the same DB server.

Same problem arises if you want to set connection specific parameter for some calls to the DB, but not all. For example the horrors surrounding the right charset (at least when working with mysql) `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);`, if some legacy nightmare let's you work with both latin-1 and utf8 content.

[edit] folks, don't use mysql_* functions! they will be deprecated soon and pose security risks. The example is only used for brevity and semantic similarity to the mssql_* functions!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand this and do not claim it is 100% correct.
If you open connection twice with same parameters, connection id will be same and this can mess up stuff, if you make transactions for example. Here comes new_link parameters - connections will use different ids and so everything should be fine.